# Putting an icon on the corner of the border of a div with :before

Tags: html, css

Apologies in advance this is my first post on SO so if I'm not giving what you need I'll try and figure it out. To give context: this is for the css of an .epub if that helps.

I am trying to place an image on the top corner of the border of multiple specific `div`s. I'm currently using `:before`, however if the `div` in question is not the first on the page, the icon isn't actually a part of the border, instead it is just at the top left corner of the page.

I made this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JGHunter/ozw7asb5/11/) to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve, but it's not quite there. The icon is in the top corner of the `div` but that's not where I want it, I want it in the top corner of the border. If I remove `position:absolute` and `position:relative` from parent and child `div` then the icon goes to the top corner of the page.

Alternatively to JSFiddle:

```css
    .other {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border: 10px solid transparent;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      }
    .info {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border: 10px solid transparent;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      border-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/YDRL4pQ/box.png) 30% round;
      position:relative;
    }
    .info:before {
        content: '';
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        background:url(https://i.ibb.co/S5zFz5r/dig-deeper.png);
        }
```

```html
Unrelated text further up the page

<div class="other">
unrelated div further up the page
</div>

<div class="info">div with text for icon</div>
```

Hopefully I've provided enough info and context! I've searched the site for similar subjects and nothing seems to be quite what I'm looking for, as my end code would look like: [image: this]. The radius in the bottom corner would be good but not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Jus use propertys `top` and `left` in `info:before` to move it over the border. See example .... ;-)

```css
.other {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.info {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/YDRL4pQ/box.png) 30% round;
    position: relative;
}

.info:before {
    content: '';
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    /* use this values for positioning 
    negative values move it over the border */
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/S5zFz5r/dig-deeper.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="other">
    unrelated div further up the page
</div>

<div class="info">div with text for icon</div>
```

Comment: Oh my god. 

Thank you.